# How to make constrains resize on every device?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, layout, constraints

I need to make log in at every device looking like in image below, I try to set constrains to image, text fields and button, but it's not looking the same on all devices, so the question is how to set constrains depends on device, that images and fields would resize on every device? I ma working on storyboard

[image]

Comment: So what want to the components to be scalable based on the screen size, right?

Comment: @AhmadF Yes, exacly what I need

Comment: Try this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

Answer (score 4):

Considering that you handle the constraints via Storybaord (for me, in most cases I prefer to do that), when a component size has to be related to the screen size, its height/width constrains should be added based on  their *Multiplayer* value.

To make it clear, consider the following example:

Here is a given scene:

[image]

Both of black and blue views sizes: `(width: 187.5, height: 66.5)`, but there is the thing, black view width/height constrains are based on *constant* value:

[image]

but the blue one constrains are based on *multiplayer* value:

[image]

As you can see, both constraints are saying: "Proportional to: Superview" meaning that their values are proportionally based on the super view's value. By selecting the width view -for example-:

[image]

Note that the `Multiplayer` value is 0.5 which means that this view (blue view) width will be the half size of the superview's width, no matter what's the value of the superview's width.

**How to add this constraint?**

- Select the desired view.
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + drag to the superview
- Choose "Equal Widths" option.

For now, it should be similar to:

[image]

Select the constraint and edit its `Multiplayer` value (from the size inspector) to the desired value.

**OR**

for even an easier trick, make sure the desired view width is equals to the superview width before adding the constraint, that makes changing the value of `Multiplayer` to be easier without showing orange constraint.

**Output:**

iPhone 7:

[image]

iPad Pro:

[image]

Blue view width is always the width of the screen, meanwhile the black one has a fixed width.

Comment: This is what I need, but another question how to make it with constrains from object to bottom and to constrain from left device side to object?

Comment: Glad to help. I think that I did't get get it :) "constrains from object to bottom": should be `Vertical Spacing to Bottom` and "constrain from left device side to object": should be "Leading Space to Container" and yes, both of constraints multiplayer is editable.

Answer (score 2):

create height Constraint for the pictures and match with controller  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWn46.png)

but there are better options with Layout

```
   @IBOutlet weak var yourConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   let size = view.bounds.size.width


    if size > 400 {

        yourConstraint.constant = 230

    }else if size > 350 {

        yourConstraint.constant = 200

    }else{

        yourConstraint.constant = 170

    }   
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should chose your object want to set in your storyboard . And click ctrl button later scroll the cursor to superview and click equalwidth/equalheight properties and set multiplier the rate you want. There it is.